# WebMatrix 3 not showing MySQL databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, webmatrix

I am new to WebMatrix and MySQL, and I need some assistance with an issue.

I'm trying to code with PHP and MySQL in WebMatrix 3. I am experimenting with scripts in a site file called "Starter PHP site". WebMatrix is not showing a database created with the `$sql="CREATE DATABASE my_db";` script when I navigate to the "Databases" section in the program. This image shows what part of the program I'm talking about.

[image: picture of the "Databases" button in WebMatrix 3]
<sub>(source: [orchardproject.net](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Upload/screenshots_675/webmatrix_opendatabase_675.png))</sub>

When I click the "Databases" button in the lower left corner of the UI, all that is shown in the left pane is a "Starter PHP site" folder icon (for creating a MySQL databse for my site from the WebMatrix UI) and an "Other Connections" icon -- but not the database created (my_db) after running the script above.

I know that the database exists...because when I run the script above again with some extras--

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxxxxxx");
    $sql="CREATE DATABASE my_db";
     if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      echo "Database my_db created successfully";
      }
     else
      {
      echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
      }
```

--I get an error saying that "my_db" already exists. Why doesn't WebMatrix show my_db in the "Databases" section...after I've run the script to create the database?

What am I missing here?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have found some sort of solution. Apparently, WebMatrix 3 might not show MySQL databases created with PHP scripts automatically, but you can view databases created with scripts by creating a new MySQL database connection to the database of interest from the WebMatrix GUI.

**Solution:** Navigate to the "*Databases*" section.... Select "*New*," then..."*MySQL Connection*." Then, enter the database information.... You should now have a working database connection.

...sorry if this is one of those newbie mistakes. I should have tried this earlier, but one might think that, since one has to establish a database connection in the PHP code, WebMatrix would automatically connect to it. For me, that isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

If it's there you should see it as such:

[image]

Dumb question, but have you tried refreshing?

Comment: Hi VoidKing,

I can create databases with the WebMatrix UI, but, when I use the script...nothing is shown. I'd like to be able to see the databases created with the script because it's just easier to understand what is being done that way. Isn't WebMatrix able to see databases that weren't created by the GUI?

Yes, I have tried refreshing.

Comment: @DanielSkrobowski Yes, any table that gets created by the GUI or programmatically, should show up here, regardless. I'm not sure why you are having trouble seeing it, but you say it "is" there because you can query it? If so, perhaps an uninstall/reinstall of WebMatrix is necessary, but I don't know. Try checking the table by adding new data and querying it back to be sure it is there. Other than that, I can't seem to see any other examples of this online, so maybe it really is a quirky install?